# Fullcalendar - remove many events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, fullcalendar-3

I have a fullcalendar.
In my fullcalendar, I have events with an id like 030820201013-trs.
Other events do not have an id that ends in 'trs'.

I would like to remove events with id that ends in 'trs'.
By doing:

```js
$ ("# calendar"). FullCalendar (' removeEvents ', [' 030820201003-trs '])
```

, it works.
However, if I do:

```js
$ ("# calendar"). FullCalendar (' removeEvents ', [' 030820201003-trs ',' 030820201005-trs '])
```

, it doesn't work.

Would you be why? And how can I delete all the events without having to loop? (Which is long enough)

Comment: The docs for [removeEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/removeEvents) states  `.fullCalendar( ‘removeEvents’ [, idOrFilter ] )` - note the `[ ]` are *not* array indicators, these indicate **optional parameters** (note the comma `,` inside the `[]`).  So looks like the `removeEvents` method is actually "removeEvent"

Comment: I understand, so it is not possible to remove all the events using an array of id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events in FullCalendar are stored as an array so there isn't really a way to remove events without having to loop through them.

You can however pass in a callback filter function to the `removeEvents` event to filter through all of events and remove the ones that end with `trs`. This function has The `Event Object` passed in which you can get the `id` from.

```js
$("# calendar").FullCalendar(' removeEvents ', ({ id }) => id.endsWith('trs'))
```

Comment: Your answer seems good to me and corresponds to my needs.
However I have an error message telling me that "endsWith" is undefined.

Is there any documentation that explains how filters work?

Comment: This is will work only if everyone of your events have ids. In v3.0, event ids were optional and could have been of either number or string type. This changed in v4.0. I would check the id variable first and then use the `endsWith` method.  `({ id }) => typeof id === 'string' && id.endsWith('trs'))`. The filter method removes events when it returns true for the event passed in. You can read more about it here [removeEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/removeEvents)

Comment: OK  !

I understand much better, having ids that don't exist, it tries to find an id ending in 'trs' in an id that doesn't exist.

Thank you very much for your help.